# Align ImageView to fully left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have been fighting with this issue but I have no idea what I am doing wrong in here.

I have a custom toolbar [code]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="10dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="10dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="10dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Gray5x" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tagActivityButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_label_white_48dp"
        android:tint="@color/red" />

    <ImageView   
        android:id="@+id/favActivityButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_48dp"
        android:tint="@color/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchActivityButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
        android:tint="@color/red" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The results are the following

[image]

The image 'android:src="@drawable/Gray5x"' should clearly be on far left but it gets in between somewhere.

Any idea how can I fix it to make the image go far left

Comment: Check if the source has any padding.

Comment: No Issue in code. Check in the layout where you are including this toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="10dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="10dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="10dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPink" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:tint="@color/colorGreen" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchActivityButton"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPink" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> Or Try this if you want all your icon to left side

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="10dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="10dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="10dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchActivityButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout inside the toolbar it will be beneficial. try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sideMenu"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cart"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_bell" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cart2"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_bell" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cart3"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_bell" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I added the center image too. If you don't want just remove it. Thank you. Hope it works for u.