# How to position menu in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have logout as a  menu item in my action bar. But the icon shows on the right of action bar. How do I position it to the left of action bar?

Here is the XML code for my menu item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout_button1"
        android:title="Log out"
        app:iconTint="@color/csrblue"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: [You can use Custom  Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925031/7666442)

Comment: AFAIK it might not be possible with menu , try using customised action bar/toolbar

Comment: @Redman, using customised toolbar worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Nilesh, thanks for the response!